# Why does bash-completion not load virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

Ubuntu 19.10 seems to have what feels like a somewhat non-standard virtualenvwrapper package which is causing me issues. But it does seem more sensible to install pip, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper from a package than to pollute the global environment outside of the virtualenv.

Most instructions ([e.g.](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/25/configuring-ubuntu-for-deep-learning-with-python/)) suggest to add the following to .bashrc:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

However, Ubuntu installs `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in `/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/`:

```
$ dpkg -L virtualenvwrapper
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bash-completion
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/virtualenvwrapper
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper
/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper/README.txt
/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/virtualenvwrapper.1.gz
/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper
/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/add2virtualenv.1.gz
...
/usr/share/man/man1/workon.1.gz
```

Fine, I can bodge it and source from that location instead, but `README.Debian` implies bash-completion should pick it up:

> In contrast to the information in
>   /usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper/html/index.html this package installs
>   virtualenvwrapper.sh as
>   /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh the lazy version is
>   installed as /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh.
>
> Virtualenvwrapper is enabled if you install the package
>   bash-completion and enable bash completion support in /etc/bash.bashrc
>   or your ~/.bashrc. The bash completion file in
>   /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper sources the lazy version of
>   virtualenvwrapper by default but can be configured to load the full
>   version instead.
>
> If you only want to use virtualenvwrapper you may just add
>
> source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
>
> to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc.

My .bashrc already appears to already contain the necessary to enable bash completion support:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

I'm running a stock Ubuntu 19.10 VM sourced from [osboxes.org](https://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/#ubuntu-19-10-vmware) inside VMWare Player on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The `virtualenvwrapper` bash completion loads the "lazy" version of script by default, which means the real wrapper script isn't loaded upon shell start; things are only really loaded when one wants to use them, such as when typing `mkvirtualenv`<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>. Quicker shell startup time, yeah, but such lazy loading can pollute console output as adverse effect, so beware of that.